# Why isn't ContentChild in Angular working as expected?

Tags: angular

I have tried different versions of this code, but still get an undefined error.

My component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterContentInit, OnInit, ContentChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-projection',
  templateUrl: './content-projection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content-projection.component.less']
})
export class ContentProjectionComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnInit {

  @ContentChild('appHeader') headerElem : ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.headerElem.nativeElement,"font-size","120px")
  }
}
```

My template that projects content:

```
<h1>Content Children - Work With Projected Content</h1>
<app-card>
  <h1 header #appHeader>My Damn Header</h1>
</app-card>
```

The component that is projected into:

```
<div>
  <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

The error:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at ContentProjectionComponent.ngAfterContentInit
```

Comment: Try to setStyle in ngAfterViewInit hook

Comment: Doesn't work. Same Error.

Comment: it is possible that it does not work because it is in app-card ng-content? try to place it outside app-card

Comment: The whole idea is to project into app-card and then use ContentChild. So, no Carles, that doesn't help.

Comment: I understand the purpose, it's just to test